# vba select/remove all sheets except first

Tags: vba, excel, select, google-sheets

I had a problem with removing unnecessary sheets. I looked at different forums and mashed up together different solutions.
This macro removes sheets (except first sheet).

```
Sub wrong()

Dim sht As Object
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If sht.Index <> 1 Then
            sht.Delete
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Is this solution ok or it can be improved?  I also tried actions directly on objects (workbooks, worksheets), but i failed each time

Comment: i forget to add: each sheet has custom name and it's different each time i need to use this macro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your code would work (but that you could have discovered by yourself!)

You could avoid the `If-Then-End` If by looping through sheets index directly from the last one to the 2nd one, as follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub wrong()
    Dim i As Long

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With Sheets '<--| reference active workbook 'Sheets' collection
        For i = .Count To 2 Step -1 '<--| loop through referenced sheets index from last to the 2nd
            .Item(i).Delete '<--| delete current index sheet
        Next
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry for that. I think that example with deleting sheets based on numeber, not position would be better if someone will mess up raport (where I'm using macro). I didn't know that i can mark only one solution :( sorry for that again

Comment: that's why I'm amateur

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong in your code. The code will delete all the sheets from the ActiveWorkbook except the first sheet.

You should declare sht as Worksheet as you know that this variable refers to the Worksheet object.

Another point is you are looping through all the sheets of ActiveWorkbook.Sheets, that means if the code is run, it will delete the sheets from the workbook which is currently active.

If you loop through ThisWorkbook.Sheets, it will delete the sheets from only the workbook which contains this code.

```
Sub DeleteAllSheetsButFirst()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If sht.Index <> 1 Then
            sht.Delete
        End If
    Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The code above will delete the sheets based on their index number i.e. their position in the workbook, not based on the sheet names.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a feedback and sugestions.   Active workbook will always be the one currently active (macro starts from button).

Answer (score 1):

Another way. This is basically pseudocode but the logic is clear. It stops automatically once you're down to sheet1.

```
sub right()
    dim wkb as excel.workbook
    set wkb = workbooks.add ' or open or whatever
    application.displayalerts = false
    do while wkb.sheets.count > 1
        wkb.sheets(wkb.sheets.count).delete
    loop
    application.displayalerts = true
end sub
```